# confusing conditional statement in a for loop

Tags: c++, c++11

I saw some code and I am astonished to see a conditional statement.
I have tried running it but the loop becomes a infinite loop.

The full code is :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int *n; 
  for (int i=0; i<5e7; i++) 
  n = new int; 
  delete n; 
}
```

How does that even compile, and why does the loop become an infinite loop?
What are these type of conditional statements?

Comment: 5e7 is scientific notation for 50000000.

Comment: The equivalent code is `for (int i=0; i<5e7; i++)  { n = new int; }`

Comment: That's a lot of memory leakage.

Comment: There is no conditional statement, only a loop.

Comment: No indentation on a bracketless for loop? *grabs a pitchfork*

Comment: Mustfa so you are saying that there is no conditional statement ina  loop?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the syntax, so the program compiles *without errors*.  Warnings are another matter and this program should generate some warnings.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ int on a 32 bit machine can hold 50 million, no problem

Comment: @AhmadBilal technically you're right, however, if you open a C++ book and look under conditional statements, you would see if ... then .. else and switch statements

Comment: Can't reproduce on my machine. How do you determine if runs in infinite time?

Comment: You should tell us why you think it wouldn't compile, because obviously it does and we know C++ so it's as unsurprising to us as it is to the compiler. We cannot correct your misconception until we know what it is.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: Is scientific notation a floating point literal or an integral literal?

Comment: @cmbasnett: That is wrong. It is scientific notation for `50000000.0`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, the scientific notation is a floating point literal. See Section 2.14.4 of the standard.

Answer (score 2):

To represent floating constants the C++ Standard introduces floating literals (
2.14.4 Floating literals )

```
floating-literal:
fractional-constant exponent-partopt floating-suffixopt
digit-sequence exponent-part floating-suffixopt
fractional-constant:
digit-sequenceopt. digit-sequence
digit-sequence .
exponent-part:
e signopt digit-sequence
E signopt digit-sequence
sign: one of
+ -
digit-sequence:
digit
digit-sequence ’opt digit
floating-suffix: one of
f l F L
```

Thus `5e7` is a floating literal. You can output it on console for example the following way

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision( 0 ) << 5e7 << std::endl;
```

and the output will be

```
50000000
```

According to the rules of the usual arithmetic conversions in this condition

```
i < 5e7
```

variable `i` is converted to type `double` (because the floating literal has type `double`)and compared with the floating literal. As soon as i will be greater than or equal to the floating literal the loop stops its iterations. It can occur in case when maximum value of type `int` is not less than the value of the floating literal.

You can check the maximum value of an object of type `int` the following way

```
#include <limits>

//...
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<int>::max() << std::endl;
```

Where I run this code I got the following result

```
2147483647
```

Thus for these values the loop can not be infinite. However maybe in your system the maximum value of `int` is less than the value of the floating literal. In this case the loop indeed will be infinite.

Comment: I didn't know the int would be converted to a float. Why is it that way and not the other way around?

Comment: @Mustafa Ozturk It is supposed that type double can contain any integer value at least irelative to their magnitudes.